# Why can i recieve broadcasts, but not communicate with a specific socket in my App?

Tags: java, android, udp, broadcast

First some Information regarding my Setup.
I have a S8 Cellphone, where i run this App, based upon the AR-Devkit demo from Google.

```
  public void closeSocket(DatagramSocket socket) {

    if (socket != null && socket.isConnected() ) {
        while (!socket.isConnected()) {
            socket.disconnect();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SpringAR.TIME_OUT_IN_BROADCAST);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d(SpringAR.protocollDebugLogPrefix, " Socket Closing interrupted");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
        socket.close();
        while (!socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SpringAR.TIME_OUT_IN_BROADCAST);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d(SpringAR.protocollDebugLogPrefix, " Socket Closing interrupted");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public DatagramSocket createSocket(InetAddress ipAddress, int port) {
    try {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, port);
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket.bind(address);

        return socket;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public DatagramSocket getBroadcastListenerSocket() throws IOException {

    InetSocketAddress anyAdress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"), 9000);
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
    socket.setSoTimeout(30);
    socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    socket.bind(anyAdress);
    return socket;
}

public DatagramSocket getBroadcastSenderSocket(DatagramSocket oldSocket) {

    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        ARDeviceAddress = InetAddress.getByName(comonUtils.getIPAddress(true));
        socket = getSocket(oldSocket, ARDeviceAddress, SpringAR.UDP_SERVER_PORT, null);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
        socket.setSoTimeout(SpringAR.TIME_OF_FRAME_IN_MS);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return socket;
}

public DatagramSocket getSocket(DatagramSocket oldSocket, InetAddress ipAddress, int port, InetAddress targetAddress) {

    if (oldSocket != null ) {
        closeSocket(oldSocket);
    }
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = createSocket(ipAddress, port);
        socket.setBroadcast(false);
        socket.setSoTimeout(SpringAR.TIME_OF_FRAME_IN_MS);
        if (targetAddress != null)
          socket.connect(targetAddress, port);

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return socket;
}

 public class DatagramReciever extends Thread {

        private String datagramToSend = "";
        private boolean newDatagramToSend = false;
        private DatagramPacket snd_packet;

        DatagramSocket senderSocket = null;
        DatagramSocket listenerSocket = null;
        private DatagramSocket broadCastListenerSocket;

        //Buffer gettters and setters
        private int writeBuffer = 0;
        private SpringAR.comStates oldState;

        int getReadBuffer() {
            if (writeBuffer == 1) return 0;
            return 1;
        }

        void switchBuffer() {
            recieveByteIndex = 0;
            writeBuffer = getReadBuffer();
        }

        public String dbg_message = "";
        //Management Communication Headers

        public void kill() {
            closeSocket(senderSocket);
            closeSocket(listenerSocket);
            closeSocket(broadCastListenerSocket);
        }



        public void run() {

            try {

                initializeBroadcastConnection();

                while (true) {

                    //Recieving Datagramm
                    DatagramPacket rcv_packet = new DatagramPacket(rcv_message[writeBuffer], rcv_message[writeBuffer].length);
                    boolean NewMessageArrived = true;
                    try {
                        listenerSocket.receive(rcv_packet);
                    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                          NewMessageArrived = false;
                    }
                    //Watchdog
                    handleWatchDogTimer(State);

                    //TODO Delete String conversion
                    if (NewMessageArrived) {
                        dbg_message = new String(rcv_message[writeBuffer], 0, rcv_packet.getLength(), "US-ASCII");
                        Log.d(SpringAR.dataDebugLogPrefix, "" + rcv_packet.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ": " + dbg_message.trim() + " of " + rcv_packet.getLength() + "length ");
                    }

                    if (validatePackageSender(rcv_packet)) {
                        connectionStateMachine(rcv_message, rcv_packet);
                    }

                    //Sending Datagram
                    if (newDatagramToSend && hostIpAddress != null) {
                        //Log.d(SpringAR.protocollDebugLogPrefix, "Server sending: " + datagramToSend);
                        byte[] snd_message = datagramToSend.getBytes();

                        try {
                            snd_packet = packSendPackageByState(snd_message);
                            assert (snd_packet != null);
                            senderSocket.send(snd_packet);
                            newDatagramToSend = false;
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            //causes     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
                            Log.e(SpringAR.protocollDebugLogPrefix, "Server Error in State: " + State.name());
                           break;
                        }

                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void initializeBroadcastConnection() throws IOException {
            ARDeviceAddress = InetAddress.getByName(comonUtils.getIPAddress(true));
            senderSocket = getSocket(null, ARDeviceAddress, SpringAR.UDP_SERVER_PORT, null);
            broadCastListenerSocket = getBroadcastListenerSocket();
            listenerSocket = broadCastListenerSocket;
            Log.d(SpringAR.protocollDebugLogPrefix, "initializeBroadcastConnection completed");
        }


        // handles management traffic like configurstion files
        private void connectionStateMachine(byte[][] payload, DatagramPacket rcv_packet) throws IOException {
            //Reset triggered by Host
            if (comonUtils.indexOf(payload[writeBuffer], SpringAR.recieveResetHeaderByte) != SpringAR.STRING_NOT_FOUND) {
                State = SpringAR.comStates.STATE_resetCommunication;
            }

            Log.d(SpringAR.protocollDebugLogPrefix, "ConnectionStateMachine: " + State.name());
            switch (State) {
                case STATE_resetCommunication: {
                    messageCounter = 0;
                    listenerSocket = broadCastListenerSocket;
                    hostIpAddress = comonUtils.getBroadcastAddress(context);
                    senderSocket = getBroadcastSenderSocket(senderSocket);
                    setSendToSpringMessage(SpringAR.sendResetHeader);
                    State = SpringAR.comStates.STATE_broadCastHeader;

                    return;
                }

                case STATE_broadCastHeader: {
                    if (comonUtils.indexOf(payload[writeBuffer], SpringAR.recieveHostReplyHeaderByte) != SpringAR.STRING_NOT_FOUND) {
                        Log.d(SpringAR.protocollDebugLogPrefix, " Host Reply Header recieved");
                        //Extract the hostIp
                        String hostIpAdressAsString = new String(payload[writeBuffer]);
                        hostIpAdressAsString = hostIpAdressAsString.replace(SpringAR.recieveHostReplyHeader, "").trim();
                        Log.d(SpringAR.dataDebugLogPrefix, hostIpAdressAsString);

                        hostIpAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostIpAdressAsString);

                        //Set Connection from broadcast to target
                        ARDeviceAddress = InetAddress.getByName(comonUtils.getIPAddress(true));
                        Log.d(SpringAR.protocollDebugLogPrefix, " New Device Adress " + ARDeviceAddress);
                        senderSocket = getSocket(senderSocket, ARDeviceAddress, SpringAR.UDP_SERVER_PORT, hostIpAddress);
                        listenerSocket = senderSocket;
                        State = SpringAR.comStates.STATE_sendCFG;
                        return;
                    }


                    setSendToSpringMessage(SpringAR.sendBroadcasteHeader);

                    delayByMs(SpringAR.TIME_OUT_IN_BROADCAST);
                    return;
                }

                case STATE_sendCFG: {
                    if ( SpringAR.STRING_NOT_FOUND != comonUtils.indexOf(payload[writeBuffer], SpringAR.recieveCFGHeaderByte )) {

                        State = SpringAR.comStates.STATE_sendRecieveData;
                        return;
                    }

                    setSendToSpringMessage(SpringAR.formConfigurationMessage());
                    return;
                }

                case STATE_sendRecieveData: {
                    if ( SpringAR.STRING_NOT_FOUND != comonUtils.indexOf(payload[writeBuffer], SpringAR.recieveDataHeaderByte)) {
                        writeRecievedDataToBuffer(payload[writeBuffer], rcv_packet.getLength());
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    Log.d(SpringAR.protocollDebugLogPrefix, "Connection State Machine invalid state");

            }


}
```

https://github.com/PicassoCT/arcore-android-sdk/blob/6c9b48a3d520e039cd48bc2af7354ccdec857736/arcore-android-sdk/samples/hello_ar/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/app/common/tcpClient/Server.java

All the testing is happening in a home-WiFi Setup, where the desktop with the host-application is directly attached to the WiFi-Router.

What is working thus far: 
The device can broadcast its presence. 
The host can broadcast its configuration.
The Device can not communicate from IP to IP on the host. Both sides have fixed IP set.

I can communicate with the App PacketSender with the host-Application, and ruled a failure on its part out.

I also built a smaller debug-loop, to only send udp-packets back and forth, which also worked.

Thank you for your time

[image: Captured Packages-Showing Broadcast going from the ARDevice to the Host-Application and a direktional Answer by the HostApplication, that is never recieved on the ARDevice]

Comment: What is not working? What specific socket can you not communicate with?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can communicate via broadcast and recieve broadcasts, but i can not send or recieve messages from one specific ip. In my testcase that is 192.168.178.178 (Host) and 192.168.178.20 (ARDevice).

Comment: Could you describe what (precisely) you have tried, what the output was, and how it differed from the expected output? What is your test procedure?

Comment: The error is with the Android Application. I can recieve broadcast communication but not packages send directly towards the ip and the socket. The packages are sent (Wireshark confirmed) and can be recieved with other applications (such as UDP Monitor).

Comment: I'm assuming that the wireshark capture was done on "Host". And further, based on that capture, it is clear that "ARDevice" is sending its datagram just fine; your question is, "Why is 'Host' not receiving/processing the datagram?" Is this correct?

Comment: "I can communicate with the App PacketSender with the host-Application, and ruled a failure on its part out." Your terminology here is unclear to me. What exactly is the "App PacketSender?"

Comment: This App: https://packetsender.com/ . And the problem is the android application only receiving broadcasts. Basically i do device discovery with broadcasts- and the moment i switch, to a directly addressing communication, the packages does not arrive on my android application. It does arrive on the socket though -as checked with another tool : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sandersoft.udpmonitor&hl=en.

Comment: Based on the wireshark capture, the app is not receiving as many direct-addressed packets as you think it is. Look at what "Host" is sending -- it's always broadcasts, at 1000ms intervals. In fact, after "ARDevice" answered that one broadcast, "Host" didn't even respond. It waited 1000ms, then just sent another broadcast.

Comment: I postponed the change for the direkt socket- and the statechmachines of host and App both took another step. So it must be something with these packets being discarded internally. I modified the App and the Host as recommended by you- resending messages until a replay arrives. Host:    https://github.com/PicassoCT/Journeywar/blob/develop/LuaUI/widgets/gui_arCam.lua   App: https://github.com/PicassoCT/arcore-android-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

`socket.setSoTimeout(30);`

to

`socket.setSoTimeout(1000);`

You've got a fairly complex state machine going here, and it's difficult to discern what is happening without having logs to look at. I would summarize your state machine like this:

1. Broadcast a configuration message
2. Spend 30ms listening for a response
3. If no response is received, block for `SpringAR.TIME_OF_FRAME_IN_MS` (not included in your code; I assume it is 1000ms), and loop back to #1
4. If a response was received, send a reply directly to the peer, and go to #2

#4 is the step that isn't happening. The likely reason (based on the Wireshark dump) is that it's taking 68ms for ARDevice's response to reach "Host". You only gave it 30ms. There could be a number of reasons it's taking so long, but that's beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: I tryied your solution, but its not a timing problem.

Comment: Fair enough, but to keep going at this, I'm going to need Wireshark captures and matching simultaneous logs (based on your `Log.d` calls) from both "ARDevice" and "Host".

Comment: Hi, i found it. The answer was two bugs. The first was my implementation of send, which dropped messages, when another message was not yet transfered. The other was - in another step - actually  not waiting for the transmission to go through- so you where right in a way- it was a timing problem, due to a logic problem. Thanks for your help.